# How can I select using LINQ for an entry that contains a LIST with more than one row?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects:

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}

public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

Which I am do a LINQ query on like this:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities });
```

Is there a way that I can filter this so I only retrieve entries that have at least one priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Eumerable.Where`:

```
var a = entries.SelectMany(x => x.Kanjis)
               .Where(x => x.Priorities.Any())
               .Select(x => new { x.Text, x.Priorities });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var e =
    from entry in entries
    from kanji in entry.Kanjis
    where kanji.Priorities.Any()
    select new { kanji.Text, kanji.Priorities };
```